# io_service_open_extended link failure

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm compiling a code using xcode. IOKit is already included in the "Link Binary with Libraries", but I still get the following errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_io_connect_method_scalarI_scalarO"
>
> "_io_service_open_extended"
>
> _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Although those two functions are defined within the program using the following code:

```
extern "C" kern_return_t io_service_open_extended
(
    mach_port_t service,
    task_t owningTask,
    uint32_t connect_type,
    NDR_record_t ndr,
    io_buf_ptr_t properties,
    mach_msg_type_number_t propertiesCnt,
    kern_return_t *result,
    mach_port_t *connection
 );
extern "C" kern_return_t io_connect_method_scalarI_scalarO(
                                                           io_connect_t conn, uint32_t selector,
                                                           io_scalar_inband64_t scalar_input,
                                                           mach_msg_type_number_t scalar_inputCnt,
                                                           io_struct_inband_t inband_output,
                                                           mach_msg_type_number_t *inband_outputCnt
                                                           );
```

But those functions can be found in Apple's API reference, and can also be googled.

Comment: The fact that you are providing your own function declarations seems to indicate that those functions are not for public consumption as you should be including a header file for the declarations.  Look at the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1050.1.21/) and see if you can find where they are declared and defined.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

set the Build Active Architecture only to NO.

Comment: Doing that will build for *more* CPU architectures, not *fewer* thereby increasing the potential for link errors, not decreasing them.  It's a knee-jerk boilerplate answer which was added with no understanding of what it does.